# Besides Augustine and Origen, did any church fathers reject a literal interpretation of Genesis 1-2:4?

Tags: exegesis, genesis, creation, church-fathers, literalism

Augustine allegorically interpreted the first creation account in Genesis 1 - 2:4 but seems to have literally interpreted the second creation account in Genesis 2:5-3:24. Origen allegorically interpreted both stories.

> "The sacred writer was able to separate in the time of his narrative what God did not separate in time in His creative act." (St. Augustine, The Literal Meaning of Genesis, translated and annotated by John Hammond Taylor, S.J., 2 vols. (New York: Newman Press, 1982) (pg. 36) [The Contemporary Relevance of Augustine's View of Creation](https://www.asa3.org/ASA/PSCF/1988/PSCF3-88Young.html)

Did any other church fathers reject a literal interpretation of at least one of the creation accounts in Genesis, or were these two the only ones to do it?

Comment: I suggest that considerable substantiation is required to verify the claims made about Augustine's and Origen's interpretations. I am looking for further detail, myself, the results of the research behind the question.

Comment: @NigelJ "The sacred writer was able to separate in the time of his narrative what God did not separate in time in His creative act." (St. Augustine, The Literal Meaning of Genesis, translated and annotated by John Hammond Taylor, S.J., 2 vols. (New York: Newman Press, 1982) (pg. 36) https://www.asa3.org/ASA/PSCF/1988/PSCF3-88Young.html

Comment: @NigelJ He held that the six days in Genesis 1-2:4 did not refer to literal days.

Comment: I believe it's a bit more nuanced regarding Augustine.  He thought it could be six literal days, or it could be a single instant that logically followed the progression in the six day account.  The latter because he thought time was an extension of the mind, and humans didn't exist to perceive time until the sixth day, so time didn't exist until humans existed.  He didn't think creation took longer than six days, and elsewhere says the history of the world was no more than 6000 years, contrary to atheists of his day who believed in an eternal universe.

Comment: @yters Is there any place where it says that creation *could* have took 6 literal days?

Comment: @TerjijKassal The rest of the Church Fathers understand it as 6 literal days. The Church has ruled that you need not hold that yom means a 24-hour period but it is by far the surest opinion. What is undisputed is that the Fathers left no room for evolution.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Origen is considered an early Church writer, but not a Church Father.  He was anathematized by a local church council in 543 and later by the 5th Ecumenical Council in 553.

Comment: @Glorius Did they leave room for non-geocentrism?

Comment: @TerjijKassal No, however, heliocentrism is not nearly as grave an error as evolution since it is only the first step of the evolutionary paradigm.

Comment: @Glorius Why do you say that heliocentrism is the first step?

Comment: @TerjijKassal If the Earth is immobile in the centre of the universe then there could've been no Big Bang, without it the whole evolutionary chronology and mechanism for "explaining" things falls apart, although it's incredibly stupid even if heliocentrism were true.

Comment: @Glorius The theory of evolution by natural selection doesn't depend on the Big Bang or Heliocentrism.

Comment: @TerjijKassal Evolution depends on a multi-billion year history of the universe which is invariably explained by the Big Bang theory and the heliocentric model. Creationists do not deny that a selection process exists in nature, the theory of evolution is not reducible to that process. Find me an evolutionist who is not a heliocentrist, when you can't, ask yourself why that is.

Comment: @Glorius You know that Darwin existed decades before the Big Bang theory? And heliocentrism doesn't say anything about how old the universe is.